# Getting issue of suspending threads while running multiple AsyncTasks

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a layout of nested Tabs with `ViewPager` in one `Fragment` of an application.

Each `Fragment` of nested fragments is showing data into `ListView` using `WebServices`.

```
public class IndicesFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
public static String imagepath = null;
static ArrayList<EquityDetails> catListDao = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
static ArrayList<EquityDetails> catListDao1 = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
static int count = 0;
static int count1 = 0;
ListView list;
ImageView progressBar;
View view;
Activity act;
AdvisorsAdapter adapter;
TextView empty_text;
private boolean isViewShown = false;
AnimatorSet set;
FetchAllData myTask;
JSONArray jsonArray;

public static IndicesFragment newInstance() {
    return new IndicesFragment();
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        isViewShown = true;
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.filter("");
        }
    } else {
        isViewShown = false;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.equity_activity, container, false);
    act = this.getActivity();
    Constants.check_fragment_visible = 1;
    count++;
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_equity);
    empty_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    progressBar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.fadein);
    set.setTarget(progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        if (catListDao.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new AdvisorsAdapter(act, R.layout.custom_equity, catListDao, 0);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            if (!isViewShown) {
                new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 3).execute();
            }
        }
    } else {
        CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(getActivity(), "There is no internet connection!");
    }
    return view;
}


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState1);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Constants.check_fragment_visible = 1;
    if (Constants.check_reload) {
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
            new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 3).execute();
        } else {
            CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(getActivity(), "There is no internet connection!");
        }
    }
    if (adapter != null) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void doChange(String queryText) {
    if (queryText != null) {
        if (adapter != null)
            adapter.filter(queryText);
    }
}


public class FetchAllData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int typeId;
    private Context cont;

    public FetchAllData(Context con, int typeId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cont = con;
        this.typeId = typeId;
        Log.d("Constructor Called", "yes");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        MainTabFragment.getInstance().myTabLayout.setClickable(false);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        set.start();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getString();
    }

    private String getString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        URL obj = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            obj = new URL(Constants.AppBaseUrl + "/call_listing/" + typeId);
            String userPassword = "rickmams" + ":" + "advisor11";
            String header = "Basic " + new String(android.util.Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP));
            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", header);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // For POST only - BEGIN
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

            os.flush();
            os.close();
            // For POST only - END

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                Log.i("TAG", response.toString());
                parseJSON(response.toString());
                return response.toString();

            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "POST request did not work.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (con != null) {
            con.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            //pDialog.dismiss();
            set.end();
            if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            MainTabFragment.getInstance().myTabLayout.setClickable(true);
            if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
                empty_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else empty_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


}

public void parseJSON(String result) {
    if (result != null) {
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            catListDao = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");

            Log.d("Length ", "" + jsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                EquityDetails allDirectory = new EquityDetails();
                allDirectory.setEntry_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("entry"));
                String value1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("entry");
                String value2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tgt_1");
                allDirectory.setSerial_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sl"));
                allDirectory.setTg_value1(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tgt_1"));
                allDirectory.setTg_value2(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tgt_2"));
                allDirectory.setPosted_by(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("posted_by"));
                allDirectory.setMainTitle_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("script"));
                allDirectory.setMain_subTitle_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("exchange"));
                allDirectory.setRating_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rating"));
                allDirectory.setReview_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("review"));
                imagepath = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("advisor_image");
                Log.d("Comminh Image ", "" + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("advisor_image"));
                allDirectory.setImage1(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("advisor_image"));
                allDirectory.setImage2(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("script_image"));
                allDirectory.setBuy(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("buy_sentiment"));
                allDirectory.setSell(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sell_sentiment"));
                allDirectory.setRecommend(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("recommendation"));
                allDirectory.setPosted_date(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("posted_date"));
                allDirectory.setCall_id(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("call_id"));
                allDirectory.setExpiry_date(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("expiry_date"));
                allDirectory.setBroker_name(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                allDirectory.setProgress_indicator(0);
                catListDao.add(allDirectory);
            }
            catListDao1 = catListDao;
            adapter = new AdvisorsAdapter(act, R.layout.custom_equity, catListDao, 0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

}
```

And the issue is app gets crashed when we change Activity from a Fragment and when we call this nested fragment from another fragment of MainActivity it gets freezed there and the fragment of nested fragments gets opened all of sudden there. The stacktrace is as:

```
 1-29 12:10:49.580 10853-10863/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.409ms
 01-29 12:10:49.707 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:27] Constructor
 01-29 12:10:49.711 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:241] attach
 01-29 12:10:49.711 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
 01-29 12:10:49.716 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
 01-29 12:10:49.717 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:56] isActive: false
 01-29 12:10:49.726 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
 01-29 12:10:49.726 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
 01-29 12:10:49.812 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:241] attach
 01-29 12:10:49.832 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:241] attach
 01-29 12:10:49.833 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi I/Choreographer: Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 01-29 12:10:50.075 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 10853
 01-29 12:10:50.610 10853-10863/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Suspending all threads took: 43.636ms
 01-29 12:10:50.621 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
 01-29 12:10:50.630 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```

And now  I'm thinking to resolve this issue by stopping and running these `Asynctasks` in `onPause` and `onResume` methods of `MainActivity`. Can anyone tell me how I can overcome of this major issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems when I tried to work with 2 async tasks. I solved the issue by commenting `toast`, `printStackTrace` and `Log`, especially in the `doInBackground()` method. This answer may sound weird but you can surely give it a try.